# Getting records from a table in a page using selenium, pandas and beautifulsoup triggered a search input

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a python script to extract records of all people in a site using selenium, beautifulsoup and pandas. I, however don't know how to go about that because the site is designed such that someone has to search first before getting the result. For test purposes henceforth, I'm passing a search value and manipulating the same via selenium. The issue is that after writing the script on a python shell in ipython, I get the desirable results, but the same is throwing an error in a python file when running via python command.

code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re

br.get(url)
content = br.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
sleep(2)
sName = br.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div/input")
sleep(3)
sName.send_keys("martin")
br.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='provider']/div[1]/div/div/div/button").click()
sleep(3)

table = soup.find('table')
tbody = table.find_all('tbody')
body = tbody.find_all('tr')
#
# get column heads
head = body[0]
body_rows = body[1:]
headings = []

for item in head.find_all('th'):
    item = (item.text).rstrip("\n")
    headings.append(item)

print(headings)
#declare an empty list for holding all records
all_rows = []

# loop through all table rows to get all table datas

for row_num in range(len(body_rows)):
    row = []
    for row_item in body_rows[row_num].find_all('td'):
        stripA = re.sub("(\xa0)|(\n)|,","",row_item.text)
        row.append(stripA)

all_rows.append(row)

# match each record to its field name
# cols = ['name', 'license', 'xxx', 'xxxx']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=all_rows, columns=headings)
```

Comment: Firstly, do not post images instead of block of code. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Secondly, the problem seems to be in the `table = soup.find('table')` . What do you get when you try print(table) ?

Comment: I'm getting none and an empty list if I use table = soup.find_all('table'). My suspicion though is on soup definition

Comment: Once you click the button `br.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='provider']/div[1]/div/div/div/button").click()` then you need to get the page source and get the soup. You have define soup before click and that's the reason you are not getting table.

Comment: This should your code before finding table. `br.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='provider']/div[1]/div/div/div/button").click()
sleep(3)
content = br.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')`

Comment: still getting none for the table

Comment: The reason I was getting 0 tables in the script its because I wasn't giving it sufficient amount of time to load and get the page_source. I resolved this by adding more time to sleep to allow the page to fully load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the overhead of a browser or to worry about waits. You can simply mimic the post request the page makes

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

data = {'search_register': '1', 'search_text': 'Martin'}
r = requests.post('https://osp.nckenya.com/ajax/public', data=data)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
results = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('#datatable2')))
print(results)
```

Comment: The issue is that the page is paginated, so I have to iterate through all the pages to get the result.

Comment: Does this not retrieve all results? If it doesn't then use the browser network tab to monitor the traffic when manually selecting next page and see what the xhr looks like for next set of results.